# Not run npm scripts as tasks in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there a way to not run npm scripts (from the sidebar) as tasks?

I'm using nvs (not nvm) in the WSL. Writing `npm run dev` in the terminal works, but clicking on the script to launch it from the sidebar outputs the following error:

```
<3>WSL (1836) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:502: execvpe npm failed 2
<3>WSL (1836) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:505: Create process not expected to return
```

[It seems](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/119619#issuecomment-806721489) running as task does not take `.bashrc` into account.

Running scripts with Bun through [this extension](https://github.com/w0o0o/bun-scripts) works fine as a temporary workaround.